# event scheduler count in if condition for a result

Tags: php, mysql, events, triggers, scheduler

I have thee following query i want to update the database if the count comes unique that is 1. I have created all this event in event scheduler mysql. But there are problems which i cannot identify. Please help me if possible, the query as below:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as cnt from auction_details a JOIN products p where p.product_id = a.product_id AND p.end_time ='2018-09-12 08:35:30' GROUP by bidprice order by bidprice
```

[image]

**THE BIDDING PRICE SHOULD BE UNIQUE TO UPDATE THE TABLE IN EVENT SCHEDULER**

I want to occur this in the event scheduler. The think i have done in the event scheduler is as follow:

```
DELIMITER |
DO
BEGIN 
DECLARE cnt AS INT;
SELECT user_id, count(*) as cnt from auction_details a JOIN products p where p.product_id = a.product_id AND p.end_time ='2018-09-12 08:35:30' GROUP by bidprice order by bidprice DESC LIMIT 1;    
IF cnt=1 THEN

SET @userid = SELECT user_id from auction_details a JOIN products p where p.product_id = a.product_id AND p.end_time ='2018-09-12 08:35:30' GROUP by bidprice order by bidprice DESC LIMIT 1;    
update products p join auction_details a on a.product_id = p.product_id join users u on u.user_id = a.user_id set p.winner = @userid WHERE p.end_time ='2018-09-12 08:35:30';
END IF;
```

END |
DELIMITER ;

Expected output is supposed to get the user id from the query which have the unique count i.e. 1 and update the products table and set the winner to be that user id.

[image]

Comment: What problems have you detect?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need sample data, current and expected output

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza .. as you can see on the expected output. I want the most unique bidprices user_id as update in the winner of the expected output area.

Comment: Dude you still havent include the sample data.Is like you show me a cake and tell me do one like this but didnt told me what are the ingridients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ON` clausule instead of `WHERE`, also `GROUP BY user_id`

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as cnt 
from auction_details a 
JOIN products p 
  ON p.product_id = a.product_id 
  AND p.end_time ='2018-09-12 08:35:30' 
GROUP by user_id
order by user_id
```

Comment: I have a problem in second part. Can u help me

Comment: what you mean second part?

Comment: When the mycnt result 1 comes i want to update the database. In this case the 2 comes from a price tag. I want unique value of my count

Comment: read my comment above, we need sample data and expected output

Comment: the expected output is in the image above.